# html format misconfiguration in Horde

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, codeigniter-2, horde

im working with codeigniter, and im new, so there are some issues that i have no idea what is going on, one of the issues is regarding the Horde webmail, when i open the email sent from the application, it would show the html tags that format the text, so i add some line of codes that i found on stackoverflow questions, but not im geting all the text splashed on the email.

Example:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_5874cd6abc9bb Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 250 dasasdasd 1 0   test@hotmail.com AirOne Continental 00135 17-01-27 OPO Porto, Portugal LIS Lisbon, Portugal Cn Wn LIS Lisbon, Portugal 250+0+0   17-01-10 12:02 Valor total: 250 Nome: dasasdasd Nr. adultos: 1 Nr. crianÃ§as:
```

I rechecked the configuration of sending the email on codeigniter, but cant found what is the problem.

My code:

```
$config = Array(

    'protocol' => 'smtp',

    'smtp_host' => 'mail.domain.com',

    'smtp_port' => 25,

    'smtp_user' => 'geral@domain.com',

    'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',

    'mailtype'  => 'html', 

    'charset'   => 'utf-8',

    'wordwrap' => TRUE

);

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
        $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
$this->email->from('geral@domain.com', 'Name');
$this->email->to('mail@domain.com'); 
$this->email->reply_to($_SESSION['email']);
$message = $this->load->view('email/finalizar_nos',$data,TRUE); // this will return you html data as message
$this->email->subject('NEW EMAIL: '. $_SESSION['name']);
$this->email->message($message);  
$result = $this->email->send();

$data['data_inserido'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->db->insert('emails',$data);

echo $this->db->insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*In Ccnfig*/

$config = Array(

    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.domain.com',
    'smtp_port' => 25,
    'smtp_user' => 'geral@domain.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'newline'   => '\r\n',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

/*Mail part*/

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('geral@domain.com', 'Name');
$this->email->to('mail@domain.com'); 
$this->email->reply_to($_SESSION['email']);

$message = $this->load->view('email/finalizar_nos',$data,TRUE); 
$this->email->subject('NEW EMAIL: '. $_SESSION['name']);
$this->email->message($message);  

if (!$this->email->send()) 
{
    echo "Error in Email sending";
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
    $data['data_inserido'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->db->insert('emails',$data);

    echo $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)